# SQLite Disk I/O error-45 Gb database

Tags: sqlite, sqlite.net

I have been using SQLite db for a while now to store my data without any problem until recently I encountered

```
disk I/O error

   at Finisar.SQLite.sqlite3.Throw()
   at Finisar.SQLite.sqlite3.exec(String sql)
   at Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteTransaction.CommitOrRollback(Boolean commit)
```

There is enough space on the local drive where the SQLite db recedes. I am running the inserts in a transaction. I suspected that the sqlite db might have got corrupted since its reached a size of 45GB, however I was able to open the db in an SQLite DB Viewer without any problem. This error is occurring on the client machine and I am unable to reproduce this in the development environment. At this point, I have no clue as to why this error is coming up. 
Can using a Single "SQLiteConnection" instance to insert 45Gb of data cause such a problem?

I use just Open the connection once in the beginning and only close once when all my insertions are completed at the end.

I would really appreciate any help from the experts out here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 45 GB is really stretching the limits of SQLite. Why not move to MySQL or another option designed to handle that kind of scale?

Comment: Also, a disk I/O error could indicate a hardware issue. Have you checked the disk itself?

Comment: Also, if you're inserting 45 GB *at one time*, which it sounds like you are, you may have other issues, including at the OS level, like paging problems.

Comment: I am inserting in batch 100 records in a transaction, The db has reached a size of 45 Gb. I see the journal files being created with some data and deleted at this stage, however the size of the db is not increasing any more. All I see the disk i/o error logs in my log file.

Comment: @EdCottrell Even with the smallest possible page size, SQLite database files can become as large as 1 TB.

Comment: Some disk (storage or temp) might have run out of space, or might be broken. `sqlite-net` does not give you access to the error log, try running your queries in the `sqlite3.exe` command-line shell with `.log` enabled.

Comment: @CL. Yes, it's certainly possible, but it's not usually a good idea. That's pretty hard on the OS and hardware. The point is that this could be an instance of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: after enabling log in sqlite3.exe commanline tool, "I get (1034) os_win.c:38149: (665) winSync2(H:\My.db) - The
Error: disk I/O error"

Comment: according to the log, it seems that it got to do with "SQLITE_IOERR_FSYNC"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the issue. The operating system error 665, indicates a file system limitation has been reached.This problem happens if a large number of ATTRIBUTE_LIST_ENTRY is needed to maintain a heavily fragmented file in NFTS.
A heavily fragmented file in an NTFS volume may not grow beyond a certain size

I formatted the drive using /L option to obtain large FRS and that solved the problem.
I would need to make sure that the db does not fragment too much.
Hope this helps somebody.